# OpenCV build problems Visual Studio 2013

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013, cmake

As it turned out, the last question I asked about OpenCV crash was a bug in OpenCV 3.0.0 beta(the official version). It was released in 2014. Since, there have many commits to the master. Anyway, now I have decided to build the library myself from the latest master. Here is what I did.

I followed the steps described everywhere. I downloaded **Cmake**. Then I opened **OpenCVGUI**. Then I put the path to the source and build destination. Next, I selected **Visual Studio 2013** and **native compiler**. I pressed configure. The problem is here:

I got the following:

```
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31101.0
The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31101.0
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
Check if the system is big endian
Searching 16 bit integer
Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - found
Looking for stdint.h
Looking for stdint.h - found
Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - found
Check size of unsigned short
Check size of unsigned short - done
Using unsigned short
Check if the system is big endian - little endian
Looking for fseeko
Looking for fseeko - not found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - not found
Check size of off64_t
Check size of off64_t - failed
Looking for assert.h
Looking for assert.h - found
Looking for fcntl.h
Looking for fcntl.h - found
Looking for io.h
Looking for io.h - found
Looking for jbg_newlen
Looking for jbg_newlen - not found
Looking for mmap
Looking for mmap - not found
Looking for search.h
Looking for search.h - found
Looking for string.h
Looking for string.h - found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - not found
ICV: Downloading ippicv_windows_20141027.zip...
```

My question is: What should I do about the "**not found**" and "**failed**" statements. I think they are going to cause problem later on. Is there any way to include every not found file or its not necessary.

Also, after the configuration I got many **NOT FOUND** values. Example **CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND** and many more. If they are vital for the build, how am I gonna get em all. I don't have CUDA SDK or MATLAB installed. How do I build it? Can anyone reading this build it for me succesfully?

I am a complete newbie to OpenCV. Please help me.

EDIT: I even tried CodeBlocks with MinGW. There are still a few NOT FOUND file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many headers are mutually exclusive, so some must be not found. They will not cause any problems later, because if they are really required, CMake would error out and indicate that the headers would be required.

How do you know that Cuda SDK and Matlab are are vital for your build? Usually they are optional features. If you rely on these features, you need to install them. But usually you are fine, until CMake errors out.